# CPTScatter plot data labels help needed

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-plot

I have been using core-plot since very beginning and I found it very flexible and feature reach, Thanks for such wonderful library that makes developers life easy.

Now problem I am facing is for data labels for graph. By default data labels are shown for each data point and I changed it to only show for third point (my graph has just 4 points and these are like (0,0),(2,34),(38,34),(40,0)). (refer attachment). All four points have same data label so just showing for third point and it's being displayed but I want to make the data label to be in canter between second and third point. I have already tried by adding layer.paddingRight/paddingLeft etc but not working, even layer.position is not working.

Some how look's like to me that position (x, y) for data label are ignored by core plot and it always draws around the point. Any help will be appreciated to get it working as I need.

Also please note that I am not using CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation as that I use for Hover info. Below is code from dataLabelForPlot: recordIndex:. Changing x and y from 0 0 to any values does not work.

```
    CPTLayer *layer = [[CPTLayer alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 300, 25)];
CPTTextLayer * newLayer = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:textToShow  style:whiteText] ;
[layer addSublayer:newLayer];
        return layer;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want the label centered between two data points, then a plot space annotation is the correct solution. You can have as many annotations on the graph as you want.

If you want the data label to always appear relative to one of the data points, use the plot's `labelOffset` to position it.

*Also answered on Core Plot [issue #239](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/issues/239).*